# Why am I getting a 403 error when creating a Fusion Table using the Ruby gem 'fusion_tables'?

Tags: ruby, google-fusion-tables

Here's my code, as per the ['fusion_tables' gem documentation](https://github.com/tokumine/fusion_tables/blob/master/README.md). Obviously, I don't post my username and password in this code.

```
require 'fusion_tables'

@ft = GData::Client::FusionTables.new      
@ft.clientlogin(my_google_account_name, my_google_account_password)

# Creating a new table
columns = [
    {
        :name=>"column_1",
        :type=>'string'
    }, 
    {
        :name=>"column_2",
        :type=>'number'
    }
]

new_table = @ft.create_table "Ruby table",columns

# Inserting rows
data = [
    {
    "column_1"=>"This is a string",
    "column_2"=>100
    }
]

new_table.insert data
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
<HEAD>
<TITLE>User does not have permission to view the underlying data</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>User does not have permission to view the underlying data</H1>
<H2>Error 403</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `create_table method` in the gem is a bit outdated.

I tried the example above, and the [boris_bikes example provided in the `fusion_tables` gem repo](https://github.com/tokumine/fusion_tables/blob/master/examples/boris_bikes.rb). Both throw the `Error 403` `User does not have permission to view the underlying data` error message on the line invoking `create_table` method.

In the above example, the line throwing this error is:

```
new_table = @ft.create_table "Ruby table",columns
```

The "Ruby_table" fusion table though is created. ( **NOTE**: The `fusion_table` gem [sanitizes the table name](https://github.com/tokumine/fusion_tables/blob/master/lib/fusion_tables/ext/fusion_tables.rb#L49), i.e. it substitutes the spaces in the given name with an underscore. )

Most likely the Google Fusion table API has changed a bit on this gem in recent times. I have [opened a new issue on the repo](https://github.com/tokumine/fusion_tables/issues/19); hopefully the developers will respond to it soon. (Or if time permit, I will dig into it, figure out the reasons, and submit a patch)

For now, I would suggest ignoring the error and continuing forward since the table is created.

After running the `new_table = @ft.create_table "Ruby table",columns` line, continue with the following steps:

```
tables = @ft.show_tables
new_table  = tables.select{|t| t.name == "Ruby_table" }.first

# Inserting rows
data = [ 
 { 
    "column_1"=>"This is a string",
    "column_2"=>100
  }
]

new_table.insert data
```

With that you should see the line show up in the Fusion Table.

On one of my Production Apps, we manually created the required Fusion Tables - merged it with existing Data tables (for which there is no API support as of now), and then use the `truncate` & `insert` methods to update the Fusion table data. So not being able to create a Fusion Table programmatically didn't come up as a big issue for us there.

Comment: The issue has been fixed now: https://github.com/tokumine/fusion_tables/issues/19